# how to check if $_GET has empty values in all the elements?

Tags: php, get

I have a form and if the user pass in nothing, the url query will have the an element name with empty value:

```
 xxx.com/?id=&name=
```

I wanted to check if the $_GET session is empty based on the values in the elements.  if(!empty($_GET)) doesn't work because it took the array elements into account. Is there a one line if statement that can do this without using the foreach loop?

Comment: Tried `if (!empty($_GET['variable'])) {
  // Do something.
}
` ?

Comment: I have so many elements in the get array, I don't want to check it one by one

Answer (score 0):

Simplest method to make use of [`in_array`](http://php.net/in_array) method:

```
echo in_array("", $_GET, true)?"has empty elements":"all elements has values";
```

---

Other way is to make use of [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter) to filter array elements whose values are empty

```
echo count($_GET) != count(array_filter($_GET))?"has empty elements":"all elements has values";
```

---

Also make sure to check if

```
count($_GET) > 1
```

in both conditions

Comment: The if (count(array_filter($_GET)) > 0) seems to work as I'm trying to check if the whole array is empty or have something, but the problem now is that when I have a value equals to 0, it was treating it as an empty value as well.

Comment: Then go for `in_array` method. Don't forget to add 3rd parameter

Comment: The in_array("", $_GET, true) is only going to check if the array has no empty value or at least one empty value, but I wanted to check for all empty values or at least one value.

Comment: use array_filter with closure to check for just empty values.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the variable instead of the array.

```
if (!empty($_GET['id']) || !empty($_GET['name']) ) { 
//code goes here...
 }
```